# Definition List Alignment with Missing Definitions

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I frequently have applications where forms have optional fields. When these records are displayed in the Show view, the definitions "collapse" together and don't line up with their respective labels. For example, if I have 3 fields and they should look like this:

```
Phone:  312-555-1212
FAX:
Mobile: 312-555-1234
```

They end up looking like this:

```
Phone:  312-555-1212
FAX:    312-555-1234
Mobile:
```

I've figured a hack to throw a non-breaking space (%nbsp) just before every closing "dd" tag, but that doesn't seem very DRY.

Is there a better way to do this with CSS?

Here is my Rails/HTML code as it stands with the non breaking spaces. It works, but, I'm trying to see if there is a better way.

```
<dt>FAX:</dt>
<dd><%= number_to_phone(@user.fax, :area_code => true) %> &nbsp;</dd>

<dt>Pager:</dt>
<dd><%= number_to_phone(@user.pager, :area_code => true) %> &nbsp;</dd>

<dt>Mobile:</dt>
<dd><%= number_to_phone(@user.mobile, :area_code => true) %> &nbsp;</dd>
```

So by putting the non-breaking space just before the closing "dd" tag, I'm tricking the system into thinking there is content in a field that doesn't have any content and putting the next item on the next line rather than moving it up so it doesn't align with it's label anymore.

Comment: You could use a basic html `<table></table>` with empty `<td></td>`. If you don't want to, maybe using the CSS rule `display: inline-block;` on the empty entity. But I am not a front-end pro, I'm not sure it'll work.

Comment: Can you paste example HTML and CSS that you've tried so far? Or a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using tables if possible. The code becomes unnecessarily complex with tables.

Comment: Updated post with Rails/HTML code of what I'm doing currently

Comment: Because this is a HTML/CSS issue, the Rails code should not be posted, as it gets in the way. As mentioned, it would be easy to suggest a solution if you post your HTML and CSS—preferably as a working example, rather than in bits and pieces.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missusing definition lists. Thy normally render like (dd of Honey is empty):
[image: definition list]

So you must use some positioning in your css to allign the "definitions"
use tables to display tables, labels to display labels and css to format it!